# install Adobe® Acrobat 9 Pro error

Tags: windows-7, installation, adobe-acrobat

My OS is Windows 7.

I try to download [Adobe® Acrobat 9 Pro](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=acrobat_pro) for English and Windows (326.6MB) by its Akamai Download Manager and then click on "Install Now". But I meet some error:

> "Action center.lnk" is a file which was downloaded from the internet. Are you sure you want to open it?

I click yes, but then:

> Launching File Failed: se_err_accessdenied

Anyone has some idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks and regards!

---

EDIT:

I think it is the "Action center.lnk" that require to be opened as adminstrator. But I don't know which software to open it? I tried Internet Explorer, but it simply copy "Action center.lnk". And another bad thing unexpected happened that all my short cut files that link to some software have their icon figures change to be the same as IE. How can I fix all these problems?

Answer (score 2):

Close Akaimi Download Manager and reopen it by right-clicking its icon and clicking "Run as Administrator."  That should iron out any kinks in permissions.

Comment: Thanks, Emory! I think it is the "Action center.lnk" that require to be opened as adminstrator. But I don't know which software to open it? I tried Internet Explorer, but it simply copy "Action center.lnk". And another bad thing unexpected happened that all my short cut files that link to some software have their icon figures change to be the same as IE. How can I fix all these problems?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use any program to open a .lnk file--that's a shortcut the application.  However, you'll need to do some registry editing to fix the default association for your shortcut files.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172053 provides a solution for Windows NT 4.0, not sure if that will still work.  Additionally, this http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/231/1/An-Utility-to-Unassociate-File-Types-in-Windows-7-and-Vista.html has been reported as working.  Be careful to download the surprisingly well-hidden zip rather than falling for the huge ad where the download button...

Comment: ...should be...